# $x < y$ implies $f (x) < f (y)$. Show that $d$ is a metric on any set, then the composition function $f \circ d$ is also a metric on $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb R_+$ denote the set of all nonnegative real numbers, and let $f∶ \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ be a continuous function such that

**(i)** $f (0) = 0$,

**(ii)** $f (x + y) \leq f (x) + f (y)$, and

**(iii)** $x < y$ implies $f (x) < f (y)$.
Show that if $d$ is a metric on any set $X$, then the composition function $f \circ d$ is also a metric on $X$.

Anyone can help to solve? It would be of great help :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "solve part (iii)"? This is a one part problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to check the properties of [metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)):

1. $f \circ d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_+$, but this is immediate since $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}_+$ and $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$;
2. $f \circ d \, (x,y) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$, which is also immediate because $d(x,y) = 0$ iff $x=y$ and $f(0)=0$;
3. $f \circ d \, (x,y) = f \circ d \,  (y,x)$ because $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$;
4. **Triangle inequality**: $$ f \circ d \, (x,z) = f(d(x,z)) \le f(d(x,y)+d(y,z))\le f(d(x,y)) + f(d(y,z)) $$where the first inequality comes from the triangle inequality for $d$ and **(iii)** while the second inequality descends from **(ii)**.